# Flutter's iOS build is updated to TestFlight but disappearing after "processing" status in Activity session

Tags: ios, flutter, build, app-store-connect, testflight

After creating the iOS build from my flutter project, I archived and uploaded it to App Store Connect via Xcode and everything went fine, no erros and no warnings.

When I went to the "Activities" section in App Store Connect, the app was in "processing" status. [Before I Control+R the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lONN1.png)

After I Control+R the page, the app was gone [and it was even suggesting me the upload tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyYMP.png)

I tried again after increasing the build version numbers and everything, but I am still having the same problem.

$flutter doctor is fine, debug is also fine (not showing any other difference between my other already uploaded flutter project and I haven't found anything like this here yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first did

```
$flutter clean
```

then

```
$flutter build ios
```

and added +1 to the project version